# Is there a token for the key of a text list?

Tags: 7, tokens, entities

I need to get the key of the key|value pair from a text list field in a token.

Say the field configuration shows the following options:

```
no|No Way Jose!
yes|Why yes, that'd do nicely!
```

and the field is named `field_doc_textlist`

the token [node:field_doc_textlist] is returning a value like '*No Way Jose!*' when what I want is '*no*'.  Is there a way to get that from tokens.  I'm using this in the filefield paths module if that matters.

I saw other similar answers here, with no real answers, but I've tried [node:field_doc_textlist:key] [node:field-doc-textlist] [node:field_doc_textlist:machine_name] [node:field_doc_textlist:machine-name] all to no avail

Some additional information: All of the above result in an error similar to

> The File path is using the following invalid tokens:
>   [node:field-doc-type-book].

A lot of the information I've found suggests using the hyphenated version of the token name instead of the underscore version, but that seems not to work at all.

Comment: I found the answer over here [option to output key value for fields of "List (text)" type](https://www.drupal.org/node/1781498) (oops pasted the wrong url before, not sure if you went there, fixed now.)

Comment: Could you be more specific about what part of that you think will fix this?  So far, nothing I'm trying is working.

Comment: did you try the sandbox module [roborew's sandbox: Entity Token Display](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/roboco/2709617) ?

Comment: I hadn't tried that yet, because it meant I was going to need to go update a  bunch of field instances, I guess I'll go try it now, and write a script to build the instances.

Comment: @NoSssweat.  I did end up using that sandbox module and it worked.  If you wouldn't mind quickly adding it to an answer I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [roborew's sandbox: Entity Token Display](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/roboco/2709617)

> This simple module was created to handle the formatting of entity
>   tokens.
>
> When using certain field entities the entity token module will provide
>   formatting and data sanitisation for display. However, there are times
>   when you need the default value of the original field.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have field_textlist on node_mytype.

- Go to admin/structure/types/manage/node-mytype/display and in the *custom display settings* tab, enable the *token* display mode
- Go to admin/structure/types/manage/node-mytype/display/token, go to field_textlist and and set *key* as formatter
- Use [node:field_textlist] (underscores) provided by token module, not [node:field-textlist] (dash) provided by entity api module.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to check that out.  I always kind of wondered about the token display because I couldn't see anywhere that is was actually affecting anything.